# función con diccionarios

Tags: python, diccionarios

pueden decirme si puedo cambiarle algo al programa? seria hacerlo un poco mas explicito/entendible,

```py
def diccionario(a):
    for c in a:
        print (c,a[c])


#programa_principal
h={'automoviles':20,'camiones':50,'motocicletas':35}
diccionario(h)
h={'escritorios':2,'sillones':23,'impresoras':5}
diccionario(h)
```

debe cumplir con esos aspectos:((

- Contenga una función con un parámetro el cual recibirá un diccionario. Una vez recibido el diccionario la función deberá recorrerlo  con un ciclo y en cada paso de ciclo imprimirá dos cosas: La clave y el valor del elemento en turno.
- Cree  por asignación directa el siguiente diccionario el cual  representa el inventario de  autos de una empresa transportadora :

```py
h= {  'AUTOMOVILES': 20 , 'CAMIONES':50, 'MOTOCICLETAS': 35  }
```

- Cree  por asignación directa el siguiente diccionario el cual  representa el inventario de  mobiliario de una empresa transportadora :

```py
h= {  'ESCRITORIOS': 20 , 'SILLONES':20, 'COMPUTADORAS':23, 'IMPRESORAS':5  }
```

El programa principal deberá hacer dos llamados a la función, en el primero se enviara el diccionario de autos y en el segundo se enviara el diccionario de mobiliario de tal manera que al correrlo aparezcan impresos los dos inventarios.

Comment: y... la pregunta es..??

Comment: solo quiero saber si puedo cambiar algo de la estructura para hacerlo quizá mas entendible o sencillo

Comment: pues ponle nombres más descriptivos a las variables, así se entenderá mejor el código

Comment: más corto imposible

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.